# NullPointerException setText Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I want to make an Android application with 2 tabs (Tab A and Tab B), and then update the content (a TextView) of the tab A, but in that case a NullPointerException raises. Here is my code :

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    TabA fragmentTabA = new TabA();
    TabB fragmentTabB = new TabB();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        addTabs();
    }

    public void addTabs() {
        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        ActionBar.Tab tab1 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab1.setText("Tab A");
        tab1.setTabListener((ActionBar.TabListener) new TabsListener(fragmentTabA));

        ActionBar.Tab tab2 = actionBar.newTab();
        tab2.setText("Tab B");
        tab2.setTabListener((ActionBar.TabListener) new TabsListener(fragmentTabB));

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);

        // I want to update the TextView of the tab A but NPE raises here
        fragmentTabA.setTextView("Hello World !");
    }
}
```

**TabA.java**

```
public class TabA extends Fragment {

    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_a, container, false);
        this.textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textview_tab_a);
        return view;
    }

    public void setTextView (String txt) {
        this.textView.setText(txt);
    }
}
```

**TabsListener.java**

```
public class TabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private Fragment fragment;

    public TabsListener (Fragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        arg1.replace(R.id.tabs_container, this.fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {
        arg1.remove(this.fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab arg0, FragmentTransaction arg1) {

    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/tabs_container" />
```

**tab_a.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_tab_a"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat**

```
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
activity ComponentInfo{com.example.actionbartest/com.example.actionbartest.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at com.example.actionbartest.TabA.setTextView(TabA.java:22)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at com.example.actionbartest.MainActivity.addTabs(MainActivity.java:35)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at com.example.actionbartest.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
10-30 19:37:36.563: E/AndroidRuntime(4287):     ... 11 more
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You are calling your setTextView method before onCreateView is called. Your textview won't exist at this point in your fragments lifecycle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it would seem that you're calling `setTextView` on `TabA` before the tab's `onCreateView` is being called, thus your setText is failing because the tab has not inflated it's view yet.

Make sure to only set the text once the view has been inflated. (and since it seems that u aren't using any kind of dynamic text, you could just set the text yourself in the `onCreateView` call)